# How do i read strings on separate lines

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to read strings on separate lines/space as title says.

I have a row on phpmyadmin which is:

[image: As the image under]

I have a made a function to get the list value on Lua and the next step would be to read every name separately and thats what i can't figure it out.

Its possible to read every line separately and then add them to an array?

As for example
**local names = {Noba, Detalle}**

Comment: What mean `to get the list value on Lua`?  Give an example of your Lua function arguments.

Comment: "_I have made a function...._" -- perhaps it would help if you shared that code.

Comment: The function its written on c++, i mean with this function i can get the "list" is shown on the image through lua, the only thing i require is to convert the list as an array via lua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
local names = {}
for _, name in ipairs(getList():explode("\n"))
   table.insert(names, name)
end
```

Comment: Did you simply try `local names = getList():explode("\n")` ?